# Eigenvectors from Johansen Test not returning stationary time series

Tags: time-series, python, stochastic-processes, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I'm using `statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen` (v0.11.0, Python 3.6) implementation  of the Johansen Test to  test for cointegration of multiple time  series, but the resulting time series constructed from the eigenvectors are not stationary despite the  results passing the trace and maximum eigenvalue tests.

Any thoughts?

[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/simulating-stock-prices-in-python-using-geometric-brownian-motion-8dfd6e8c6b18)

```
## Simulate some Geometric Brownian Motion time series

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.seed(42)

def Brownian(N):

    dt = 1./N                                    # time step
    b = np.random.normal(0., 1., int(N))*np.sqrt(dt)  # brownian increments
    W = np.cumsum(b)                             # brownian path
    return W, b

def GBM(So, mu, sigma, W, T, N):    
    t = np.linspace(0.,1.,N+1)
    S = []
    S.append(So)
    for i in range(1,int(N+1)):
        drift = (mu - 0.5 * sigma**2) * t[i]
        diffusion = sigma * W[i-1]
        S_temp = So*np.exp(drift + diffusion)
        S.append(S_temp)
    return S, t

So = [1 for n in range(5)]
mu = [np.random.normal(0) for n in range(5)]
sigma = [np.random.normal(0) for n in range(5)]
N = int(2**6)
W = Brownian(N)[0]
T = 1.

df = []
for n in range(5):
    a,t = GBM(So[n], mu[n], sigma[n], W, T, N)
    df.append(a)

# Convert to DataFrame
dat = pd.DataFrame()
for n in range(5):
    dat[n] = df[n]

dat.plot()
```

[image: Simulated GBM Time Series]

```
## Cointegration Test

from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen

res  =  coint_johansen(dat, 0, 1)
print(f'Max Eig: {res.max_eig_stat[0]}, {res.max_eig_stat_crit_vals[0]}')
print(f'Trace: {res.trace_stat[0]}, {res.trace_stat_crit_vals[0]}')
--
[OUT]
Max Eig: 90.7607428, [31.2379, 33.8777, 39.3693]
Trace: 167.67532948, [65.8202, 69.8189, 77.8202]
```

The first eigenvector's trace and maximum eigenvalue tests are significant at the 99% level. However the constructed time series is clearly not stationary:

```
# First cointegrating vector normalized first component to 1
v1 = res.evec[:,0]/res.evec[:,0][0]

keys = [x for x in dat.columns]
w = pd.Series(dict(zip(keys,v1)))
dat.multiply(w, axis=1).sum(axis=1).plot()
```

[image: Non-stationary time series]

Comment: My understanding of the Johansen test is that it is not checking for general non-stationarity, but rather if the number of non-stationary patterns considered significant is less than the  number of original time series.  It is not the first eigenvector that matters but if the rank of the last significant PC is less than (in your example) 5.  According to math theory one expects random walks to deconvolve into different frequencies, so non-stationarity will appear.  What matters is whether the PCs concentrate the non-stationarity into fewer PCs than observed time series.